# No data transfer to Access with ADODB recordset

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have created an excel linked access database with VBA that works when I use a centrally saved version but not when I save a local copy.

I have used the Debug tool and the code skips my For loop in the locally saved copy.

```
For x = 2 To nextrow
        DatabaseData.AddNew
        For i = 1 To 35
            DatabaseData(Cells(1, i).Value) = Sheet18.Cells(x, i).Value
            Next i
            DatabaseData.Update
        Next x
```

I think that this is because the Recordset (DatabaseData) is not being recognized (not sure if that is the correct term).

The code is below

```
Sub CopyDatatoAccess()
    Dim DatabaseConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim DatabaseData As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Pathway
    Dim x As Long, i As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long

    On Error GoTo errorhandler:

    Pathway = Sheet18.Range("AQ2").Value
    nextrow = Sheet18.Range("AR2")


    Set DatabaseConn = New ADODB.Connection

    If Sheet18.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "ARF form is not present for Upload"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    DatabaseConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Pathway

    Set DatabaseData = New ADODB.Recordset

DatabaseData.Open Source:="ARFs", _
    ActiveConnection:=DatabaseConn, _
    CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, _
    LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
    Options:=adCmdTable

For x = 2 To nextrow
    DatabaseData.AddNew
    For i = 1 To 35
        DatabaseData(Cells(1, i).Value) = Sheet18.Cells(x, i).Value
        Next i
        DatabaseData.Update
    Next x

    DatabaseData.Close
    DatabaseConn.Close

    Set DatabaseData = Nothing
    Set DatabaseConn = Nothing

MsgBox "The ARF is now uploaded"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheet18.Cells.Range("AK2").Value = Sheet18.Cells.Range("AK4").Value + 1

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub
errorhandler:

    Set DatabaseData = Nothing
    Set DatabaseConn = Nothing
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Export_Data"
    End Sub
```

Comment: When you are using the debugger, once you get to your for loop, what is the value of nextrow?

Comment: It says 7 for To `nextrow` but at the bottom of the loop next x value is 2 and doesn't update so I end up with one full loop but no data is uploaded

Comment: so it goes and displays the messagebox and turns on screenupdating after skipping your loop?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the nextrow function isnt working fully as when I try to upload multiple recordsets from the file it skips some lines ie i use it once and everything is fine. I then use it again it will miss some of the lines when it tries to upload

Comment: just a thought, maybe try setting nextrow = Sheet18.Range("AR2") to nextrow = Sheet18.Range("AR2").value

Comment: Unfortunately it still skips the first month of a two row activity the value of AR2 for this was 2

Comment: Thinking about this for a second, your loop is using 2 to the value in the cell, is all of your data actually in the first two columns of the sheet?

Comment: Nope, the columns are 1 to 35 and the rows are from 2 to 13. I changed AR2 to equal the count of rows with data + 1 and now all the data is present for the upload - thanks for taking the time to look at this :) sorry for the simple question

Comment: Ok, well there you go!